# How to centerally zoomin background image when mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
**HTML**
<div class="bimage">
    <img class="fimage" src="http://tinyurl.com/luzr4fr"/>
</div>

**CSS**
.bimage {
    display: flex;
    border:2px solid red;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background:url('http://tinyurl.com/orwbgck');
    background-size:100%;
}
.bimage:hover{
        background-size:120%;
}

.fimage {
    width: 200px; 
    margin: auto;  
}
```

Here I can zoom in image when mouse over on that image. But I need centerally zoom in image and animation effect with out increasing div width and height.
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j90zzsct/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `background-position:center` along with `background-size`

```css
.bimage {
    display: flex;
    border:2px solid red;
    width:100%;
 height:300px;
 background:url('http://tinyurl.com/orwbgck');
    background-size:100%;
    transition:1s all;
  background-position:center;
}
.bimage:hover{
  background-size:200%;
    
}

.fimage {
    width: 200px; 
    margin: auto;  
}
```

```html
<div class="bimage">
    <img class="fimage" src="http://tinyurl.com/luzr4fr"/>
</div>
```

Comment: once you set `background-position:center` on the parent class you can skip it on the hover..

Comment: @MorKadosh I figured it out a bit later added it now...:)